# Nodejs and redis structured data

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-structures, node-redis

I am trying to set up a redis cach system. I have Json data coming in and I want  to store it in a specific way!
Currently im trying to just have an ordered list as there will be lots of data stored here before deleting.
The basic data i am using is

```
{
    user_id: "123456789"
    acc_x: "123456789"
    acc_y: "123456789"
    acc_z: "123456789"
    time: "123456789"
}
```

The way I would like to store it in redis is something like this:

```
user_id:"123456789" -> acc_x:"123456789" , acc_y:"123456789" ,acc_z:"123456789" , time:"123456789"
```

Ive tried with two variables like this

```
//Where temp is a place holder for values
client.mset("AccelX", temp_x,"AccelY", temp_y, redis.print);
```

This approach does not work and I am just confused as to how to do it if anyone knows a way or any documentation that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead use

client.hmset ("123456789", "acc_x", "val 1", "acc_y", "val 2")

Refer the following links :

http://redis.io/commands/hmset

https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/blob/4f9c6bd21912b1404089777d4e409d7a55ce1250/test.js